# Higher regularity for linear parabolic equation with time depndent coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I am looking for a higher regularity result for the solution of the problem

```
$$\partial_t u+div(-A(t,x)\nabla u)=f$$
```

in a bounded smooth domain $\Omega$ with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition.
What should be the minimum regularity I should assume for $A$, $f$, and the initial condition such that my solution lies in some $H^k$ space with $k>2$? Also, I would like to know the energy estimates for the $H^k$ norm.

Note: Evans PDE book discusses the case when $A$ is a constant matrix but I am looking for situation where $A$ is both space and time-dependent, bounded, and elliptic.

Comment: Have you tried “Second Order Parabolic Differential Equations” by Lieberman?